# R - Nested IF statements with grep

Tags: r, regex, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to tag some rows in my data based on a couple of criteria in my data frame.

My data looks like:

```
X <- structure(list(Website = c("www.something.at", "www.something.nl", "www.something.ch", "www.something.dk", "www.something.at"), 
                    Country = c("German", "Netherlands", "German", "Denmark", "Austria")), 
                    .Names = c("Website", "Country"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I need to do is add a new column which tags the data in a new column based on certain criteria. So where the country equals German I need to look at the website URL and using the IF function tag it with a different country name. I.e. Austria or Switzerland.

I have got to the below and I'm hoping I'm missing something really simple, but the code works fine for tagging Switzerland, but in all other cases everything gets tagged as Austria.

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
    if(length(grep("German", X$Country[i]))>0)

    if(length(grep("\\.at$", X$Website[i]))>0)
    X$Website_2[i] <- "Austria"

    else
    if(length(grep("\\.ch$", X$Website[i]))>0)
    X$Website_2[i] <- "Switzerland"

    }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: seems to me that you mixed up your if else statements a little?! What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for? (btw something seems to be wrong with your dput, it states that there are 10 rows, but there are only five values, so I changed that here too.

```
> X <- structure(list(Website = c("www.something.at", "www.something.nl", "www.something.ch", "www.something.dk", "www.something.at"), 
+                     Country = c("German", "Netherlands", "German", "Denmark", "Austria")), 
+                     .Names = c("Website", "Country"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
> 
> 
 #we use upper to make it robust against multiple capitalization schemes
 #instead of nesting another ifelse, we use the fact that we can add to logical values
 # and use the returned number to index into out country vector.
> X<-within(X,
+           cleanCountry <- ifelse(toupper(Country)=="GERMAN",
+                           c("Switzerland", "Austria")[1+grepl("\\.at", Website)],
+                            Country))
> X
           Website     Country cleanCountry
1 www.something.at      German      Austria
2 www.something.nl Netherlands  Netherlands
3 www.something.ch      German  Switzerland
4 www.something.dk     Denmark      Denmark
5 www.something.at     Austria      Austria
```

Comment: Thanks @JPC, realise now my dput was wrong - thanks for correcting.

I get this and it works in re-coding Austria and Switzerland. I'm not sure how you then got the other countries in. You say index into the country vector and I can see I've got a unique number associated with each country. But how do I then add that to the data set - so I have something like your output rather than Austria, Switzerland and then the unique ID?

Comment: Ah got it. Used library(plyr)
y <- join(df, lookup, by = "cleanCountry")

Comment: by using `within` you can make modifications to the data.frame, so we create a column called `cleanCountry`. If our `Country` not German, then we just return that `Country`, if it is, then we check if `Website` ends with `.at`, if it does that will be `TRUE` else `FALSE`. We add 1 to these values, s.t `TRUE` becomes 2 and `FALSE` becomes 1, and with that we index into the switzerland/austria vector. So after you do this, you should already have that column in your original data.frame, does that clarify?

Comment: Hey @JPC that did clarify thanks. For whatever reason something in my data meant the names weren't returned. Your script was right I just had to add as.character to the end of the script, otherwise it just returned the index number for some reason.

Comment: Did you try to assign back into `Country`, or did you create a new column `cleanCountry`? If you did the former, what happened was that `Country` was a factor column. Switzerland was not initially one of the values in your `levels`, so when you tried to assign into that column, rather than stopping you it converts the original factors into the integers that underly it and converts these into characters. consider the following: > a<-as.factor(c("a","b","c"))
> a
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
> a<-c(a,"d")
> a
[1] "1" "2" "3" "d"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` to avoid working with `for` loops. This is one way:

```
# Your data was a little messed up.
X<-data.frame(Website = c("www.something.at", "www.something.nl", "www.something.ch", "www.something.dk", "www.something.at"))

# A simple way.
X$Website_2<-NA
X$Website_2<-ifelse(grepl("\\.dk",X$Website),'Germany',X$Website_2)
X$Website_2<-ifelse(grepl("\\.at",X$Website),'Austria',X$Website_2)
X$Website_2<-ifelse(grepl("\\.ch",X$Website),'Switzerland',X$Website_2)
```

A slightly more elegant solution would use a mapping table for country codes and countries.

```
# A more elegant solution
X<-data.frame(Website = c("www.something.at", "www.something.nl", "www.something.ch", "www.something.dk", "www.something.at"))

map<-data.frame(country.code=c('dk','at','ch'),
                Country=c('Germany','Austria','Switzerland'))
#   country.code     Country
# 1           dk     Germany
# 2           at     Austria
# 3           ch Switzerland

X$country.code<-gsub('.*\\.([^\\.]*)$','\\1',X$Website)
merge(X,map,all.x=TRUE)

# country.code          Website     Country
# 1           at www.something.at     Austria
# 2           at www.something.at     Austria
# 3           ch www.something.ch Switzerland
# 4           dk www.something.dk     Germany
# 5           nl www.something.nl        <NA>
```

Not that the Netherlands were not mapped because it wasn't in the `map` `data.frame`.